# Loop over 3 lists that is inside a map

Tags: java

I have a map which consists of 3 lists as follows.

```
User user = new User();
user.setId(1);
// more user creation 

List<User> usersOne = Arrays.asList(user1, user2, user3);
// more lists created 

// This is the map with 3 lists. Adding data to map 
Map<String, List<User>> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("key1", usersOne);
map.put("key2", usersTwo);
map.put("key3", usersThree);
```

Above is just to show example. This map is constructed this way and coming from a rest call.

Is there a way I could loop over those lists for all 3 keys and add per item to a new list?

Meaning like this.

```
List<User> data = new ArrayList<>();

List<User> list1 = map.get("key1");
List<User> list2 = map.get("key2");
List<User> list3 = map.get("key3");

data.add(list1.get(0));
data.add(list2.get(0));
data.add(list3.get(0));

// and then 

data.add(list1.get(1));
data.add(list2.get(1));
data.add(list3.get(1));
```

and so on. Or a better way to do it. Ultimate looking to get a new list of the users by getting them in this manner, 1 from each list and then move on to next index.

Note that the 3 lists are not of same length.

Was looking to see if I could achieve it via something like the following.

But looks expensive. Could I get some advice on how I could achieve this?

```
for (User list1User : list1) {

    for (User list2User : list2) {

        for (User list3User: list3) {

            // write logic in here since I now do have access to all 3 lists. 
            // but is expensive plus also going to run into issues since the length is not the same for all 3 lists. 

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `map.values().flatMap(List::stream)` would return a `Stream<User>` of every user within the map's lists. Is there a more specific case you need than that?

Comment: @Rogue Thanks. I need the result to be in order like list1 index 0, list2 index0, list3 index0, list1 index 1, list2 index 1 and so on. Believe the above would result in, list1 index0, list1 index1 (should have been list2 index1).

Comment: The fact that the lists come from a map and the map comes from rest is completely irrelevant to the question and really confused me. It would have been better to leave them out of the question. Your question is simply about adding elements from 3 lists into 1 new list.

Comment: @GonenI Noted. Added that in case answers suggest to change the map itself. Wanted to point out that it is not in my control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple solution for your problem is "use index".

```
int size1 = list1.size();
int size2 = list2.size();
int size3 = list3.size();
//Choose maxSize of (size1,size2,size3)
int maxSize = Math.max(size1,size2);
maxSize = Math.max(maxSize,size3);
```

then use single loop, only add with condition i < listSize:

```
for(int i=0;i<maxSize;i++){
  if(i < size1) data.add(list1.get(i);
  if(i < size2) data.add(list2.get(i);
  if(i < size3) data.add(list3.get(i);
}
```

In case you have more than 3 list in map:

```
    Collection<List<Object>> allValues = map.values();
    int maxSize = allValues.stream().map(list-> list.size()).max(Integer::compare).get();
    List<Object> data = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0;i<maxSize;i++) {
      for(List<Object> list: allValues) {
        if(i < list.size()) data.add(list.get(i));
      }
    }
```

Ps: you might get warning because i am using notepad++ not editor tool.

Answer (score 0):

Not very simple but very concise and pragmatic would be to extract the lists from the map, flatten them and then collect them. Since Java 8 we can utilize [streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) for that.

```
List<User> data = map.values().stream()
  .flatMap(users -> users.stream())
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

With `.values()`  you get a `Set<List<User>>` of your UserLists, i assume, that you don't need the keys.
With `.flatMap()` we gather all users from each list. And we use `flatMap()` instead of `map()` because we want to retrieve the users from each list.

The last method-call `.collect(Collectors.toList()` collects all elements from this stream and puts them into a [read-only-list](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList(java.util.List)).
In this case, you would preserve multiple occurrences of the same user, which you wouldn't if you collect them as a set `collect(Collectos.asSet())`, given they are really different objects.